# Selenium WebDriver + Firefox 7.0.1 incompatibility

Tags: firefox, selenium

I have a project where we have some Selenium tests. I have recently upgraded Firefox to 7.0.1 because it prompted me to and now the "WebDriver for Firefox" extension that these tests use is broken.

[image: Firefox WebDriver is broken]

How can I fix this? Must I uninstall this current version of Firefox and install an older one? Or is there a file I can edit to tell it to ignore that the version is different?

Comment: Could you consider using capybara-webkit instead of selenium?

Comment: @parndt: No, this project is already well established and we tried capybara-webkit and found it to be at least twice as slow as Selenium.

Comment: Rule of thumb is a new version of a browser normally means you need to update your version of Selenium

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's way out of date...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An upgrade to Selenium webdriver to 2.8 would probably solve it.

http://web.archive.org/web/20120115040501/http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/tags/selenium-2.8.0/rb/CHANGES

Unfortunately this has been the case for every Firefox upgrade since 5.0

Comment: Confirm, upgrading to selenium-webdriver fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would try with the latest selenium-webdriver. I run Firefox 7.0.1 as well and it works with selenium-webdriver 2.8.0.

Answer (score 3):

You can tell Firefox to ignore plugin and extension versions.

1. Type `about:config` in the browser address bar
2. Right-click and create a new boolean value called `extensions.checkCompatibility.7.0`
3. Set this value to false

That should prevent the plugin raising an issue with its version compatibility to 7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

i am working with FF-8. Just change the firefox version from standalone.jar. For this unzip your jar file with unzipper and search for install.rdf files in the unzipped files. Open them in word pad and change version. you can add the latest version of browser. There are five or six files that to be changed. after doing that again zip them change to extension .jar